# Express JS does not perform delete

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

PUGJS script

```
form(id="form1" action="/delete" method="POST")
input(type="submit",name=+item['id'] value="delete")
```

My ExpressJS code

```
router.post('/delete', function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.params("i");
    console.log("i am 0")
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        console.log("i am 1")
        db.collection('books', function(err, book) {
            db.collection.deleteOne( {_id: new mongodb.ObjectID(id)} );
            console.log("i am 2")
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                db.close();
                res.redirect('/');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Trying to perform a delete request but it does not even print ("i am 0") 
can not determine what's broken with the code

NPM response  **POST /delete 404 7.247 ms - 1202**

Comment: `deleteOne` method should expect callback.

Comment: Are you sure , the execution went into the code for `router.post('/delete' ` . Please use try.. catch statements in the code to find out where and what the error is. Please provide details which can be helpful for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see a 404 the root cause is definitely how you set up the routing.  This code would be successfully called if it is in app.js/server.js (or whatever your root express file is), but a 404 means that you have placed it in a secondary file and are using another path in there somewhere.

With that said, you also have an issue with how your route is defined if you want to read a route parameter (which is what the first line of your route handler tries to do).

```
router.post('/delete/:i', function...
```

The form itself isn't passing any id though through name (or id).  You could either pass the id through the url called:

```
action= "/delete?id=" + id
```

...and read this in your route handler using `req.query.id` or you could insert a hidden input in the form and read it using `req.body.id`.

Also, the form `name` attribute [has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) and should be replaced with `id`.

Then, it's important to note that pug is highly dependent on indentation.  Your code as pasted will generate an empty form and a separate input field.

This:

```
form(id="form1" action="/delete" method="POST")
input(type="submit",name=+item['id'] value="delete")
```

Generates this HTML:

```
<form id="form1" action="/delete" method="POST"></form>
<input type="submit" name="itemId" value="delete">
```

If you change the pug template to this (note the two additional spaces on the input line):

```
form(id="form1" action="/delete" method="POST")
  input(type="submit",name=+item['id'] value="delete")
```

You will get this, which should work as expected:

```
<form id="form1" action="/delete" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" name="itemId" value="delete">
</form>
```

Then, there's the problem in your [delete function](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#deleteOne) where you're missing a callback.

```
db.collection.deleteOne( {_id: new mongodb.ObjectID(id)} );
```

You need to either add a promise or callback here otherwise your code will move straight to close the connection.